# How to make a package be visible for a computer

Tags: python, package

I'm really interested in creating a package in python. To do so, I watched and read several tutorials but there is always something that doesn't want to work.

**What I'm doing**

I created a folder `package__tutorial` in which I have another folder which corresponds to the name of my package - `mypackage`.

Folder `mypackage` contains two files:

1. `__init__.py` - file which indicates where the package is
2. `functions.py` - file which contains functions to be included into the package

In functions.py have some one basic function:

```
def average(x,y):
    return (x+y)/2
```

To summarize - my file structure is the following

`package__tutorial` containing `mypackage` containing `__init__.py` and `functions.py`.

I tried to load my package using `import mypackage` and then use `average(2,8)` but I get message that `name 'average' is not defined`. It seems that my computer doesn't see my newly created package. Have I done something wrong/something is missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an issue with how you are importing. Since `average` is a function in `functions.py`, you would have to import the `functions` module from the `mypackage` package.

```py
from mypackage import functions
functions.average(2, 8)
```

If you only want to call `average` instead of `functions.average`, you can use the wildcard import.

```py
from mypackage.functions import *
average(2, 8)
```

Be careful with this method, however, since issues may arise with modules with similarly named functions are are imported with the wildcard import.

Comment: Okay I see it's working.. however I have one question. If I delete "functions" from "functions.average(2,8)" program refuses to work saying that there is no function such average. Is there any possibility to import this in such way that I will not always have to use average preceded by "functions" ? i.e. preferably to use only "average(2,8)" instead of "functions.average(2,8)"

Comment: @John I updated my answer to allow you to call `average` instead of `functions.average`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `import mypackage` then you need to call the method with `mypackage.mymethod()` Alternatively, if you only want mymethod from mypackage, use

```
from mypackage import mymethod
```

`mymethod()`